# How to get the report between certain date range in Cognos

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, timestamp, cognos, cognos-8

I have recently started working on Cognos Report Studio. had a T-sql code with 4 table joins. I simply pasted the code in Cognos Report Studio by dragging the SQL toolbox to Query Explorer. The report did run successfully. But now I want this report generated on 1st of every month with maturity date falling between 1st to 30th/31st of that month. 
For Eg: If I get a report on 1st May, It should give records of data where the maturity date range is between 1st may to 31st may. 
I tried adding the below code to my already written SQL code:

```
WHERE 
CURR_MATURITY_DATE BETWEEN (DATEADD(MM, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND (DATEADD(MM, 0, GETDATE()) +1, 0) -1)
```

This code doesn't work.
Pl Note: THe format of column CURR_MATURITY_DATE is: mm/dd/yyyy. Please advise what changes are required in the code to run successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognos has an add months function. (At least, Cognos 10 does.)  In your expression editor, on the functions tab, it's under Business Date/Time Functions.  It's called _add_months.  So your function would end up being something like `between (_add_months(1,current_date))`

You can also use the SQL Server function.  You have to put those text parameters (like MM) in curly brackets. So you would end up with `dateadd({MM},0,current_date)`.

For the first day of the current month, in TSQL you would use:`DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`
In Cognos, the syntax would be `DATEADD({MONTH}, DATEDIFF({MONTH}, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`

Comment: I tried in SQL code CURR_MATUR_DT BETWEEN((DATEADD({MM}, 0, current_date), 0) AND (DATEADD({MM}, 0, current_date) +1, 0) -1) but didn't work

Comment: I don't know why it is still giving me the error. WHERE  CURR_MATUR_DT BETWEEN ((DATEADD({MONTH}, DATEDIFF({MONTH}, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AND (DATEADD({MONTH}, DATEDIFF({MONTH}, 0, GETDATE()) +1, 0) -1))) Error: An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlPrepareWithOptions' status='-9'

Comment: What's the actual error?  You may have to click on details.

Comment: Would you suggest to use convert function for Getdate as the Curr_Maturity column returns date in mm/dd/yyyy format?

Comment: That shouldn't matter, as long as the column is a date column.

Comment: The details doesn't really provide the exact details of the error. It says 'CAF-WRN-2082 An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator. The complete error has been logged by CAF with SecureErrorID:2014-04-30-17:42:44.549-#9523'

Comment: Crud. If you have access to your Cognos logs, or the audit database, you should be able to pull the error out that way.  If not, I would use SQL directly against the database to see what's going on.

Comment: Currently in office, I have access only to report studio. Will try this at home. Anyways thank you so much for your valuable time and inputs. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try these in your WHERE clause:

For first day of the month: `select DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate()), 0)`

For last day of the month : `select dateadd(ms,-3,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,getdate()  )+1, 0))`

Find it [here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3076421/Examples-of-how-to-Calculate-Different-SQL-Server-Dates.htm), it explains all.